# Simple question on DPLYR package: What is the behaviour in R that is preventing me from executing this sort of command?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working through "R for Data Science" by Wickham and Groleman and the following question was asked in the exercises *(The question uses the "nycflights13" data set that comes preloaded in Tidyverse)*:

**Use geom_tile() together with dplyr to explore how average
flight delays vary by destination and month of year. What makes
the plot difficult to read? How could you improve it?**

Course of action:

So my idea was to create a new variable called `avg_arr_delay` and use this in conjunction with the fill aesthetic to create a visual representation. Before progressing to the visual representation I attempted to look at my specified data in table form. I used the following command:

```
View(flights %>% count(month, dest) %>% group_by(month) %>% 
mutate(avg_arr_delay = sum(arr_delay)/sum(n)))
```

So my thought was that since I grouped the data by month that R would take that into consideration with regards to the `arr_delay` column and compute the sum of all entries corresponding to their respective month. Example: all of Month 1's `arr_delay` entries get summed together, etc.

But alas I get an error when I attempt this:

`Error in View : object 'arr_delay' not found`

So my question now is how is R interpreting my code when I attempt to create these new variables ?

Comment: Did you look at the output of `flights %>% count(month, dest)`? There is no longer a `arr_delay` column. Maybe you wanted `add_count` instead?

Comment: You are onto the idea I was having issue with. I reduced my table once I only included `(month, dest)`. I never took this into consideration. I'm going to try `add_count` right now and see how it works.